# no error or result when trying to use PowerShell execute a .bat file on a remote PC

Tags: batch-file, remote-server

I have read many examples of how to run a .bat file on a remote PC and the one I need is based on the PowerShell invoke-command:

```
invoke-command -computername RemotePC -scriptblock {start-process c:\things\Thing.bat}
```

When I run that line of PowerShell it does not run the .bat file on the remote pc and returns no error. Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this works:

```
invoke-command -computername RemotePC -scriptblock {& "c:\things\Thing.bat"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Start-Process` isn't intended to be used to start scripts but instead to start processes, e.g. real exectuables.

You have some alternatives though (one you allready found):

- Using the Dot sourcing `{. "C:\things\thing.bat"}`
- Using the Call operator `{& "C:\things\thing.bat"}`

Differences between both operations [(ref.: Source-Powershell-SS64)](http://Dot%20sourcing%20runs%20a%20function%20or%20script%20within%20the%20current%20scope.%20unlike%20the%20call%20operator%20(&)%20which%20will%20run%20a%20function%20or%20script,%20but%20it%20is%20not%20added%20to%20the%20current%20scope.):

> Dot sourcing runs a function or script within the current scope.
>   unlike the call operator (&) which will run a function or script, but
>   it is not added to the current scope.